# Determine the number of rows in txt file using windows console tools

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

There is a text file with an unknown number of rows like this:

$ cat test1 

123

abc

456

def

...

def

123

456

def

abc

456

123

Using the windows console tools it's necessary to determine the number of rows '123'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the number of occurrences of a string in file using windows command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307187/how-to-find-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-in-file-using-windows-command)

Comment: I don't think they're looking for the number of times 123 appears in the file; I think they're looking for the number of lines in the file, like the Windows equivalent of `wc -l` (since I see you're using `cat`, I'm assuming you have Gnu Tools or something installed).

Comment: FIND command with the /V and /C options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is the complete content of the line

```
findstr "^123$" test.txt |find /C "123"
```

If you want the result be put in a var on the cmdline

```
For /f %A in ('findstr "^123$" test.txt ^|find /C "123"') Do set Var=%A
```

If you want the result be put in a var inside a batch

```
For /f %%A in ('findstr "^123$" test.txt ^|find /C "123"') Do set Var=%%A
```

Comment: Cool! It works! But what if 123 is the last row in file?

Comment: If that last line has no crlf that wouldn't be counted. Maybe you could append a  crlf by `>>test.txt echo:`