# Count occurences of string (from txt file) in text file and export to CSV or txt file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have used different sources here on Stack Overflow, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246765/windows-batch-scripting-collect-unique-occurences-of-a-string-in-a-file), to clean my alarm file (data.txt) from spam and to extract the unique occurences to this file (unik.txt). The next step, where i am stuck, is to use unik.txt and count the number of occurences in data.txt, and to export the string and count to a text or csv-file.
As you may have guessed it is a way of creating an alarm statistic. I have considered using other methods/languages but will first want to try this way.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307187/how-to-find-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-in-file-using-windows-command) post also without coming to a close.

Extract from data.txt:

```
D_TA204_GT1_DV_AL
D_TA204_GT41_DV_AL
D_TA204_GT31_DV_AL
D_TA204_GT21_DV_AL
U_TA364_GT11_LARM
U_TA364_GT11_LARM
U_TA364_GT11_LARM
U_FF415_GT46_L_AL
U_TA364_GT11_LARM
D_TA204_GT31_DV_AL
U_KB6_GT11_DV_AL
U_FF415_GT46_L_AL
D_TA204_GT21_DV_AL
U_KB6_GT11_DV_AL
TRE-11-11-I033
TRE-11-11-D5394
U_KB6_GT11_DV_AL
U_KB6_GT11_DV_AL
U_KB6_GT11_DV_AL
```

Extract from unik.txt:

```
D_TA204_GT1_DV_AL
D_TA204_GT41_DV_AL
D_TA204_GT31_DV_AL
D_TA204_GT21_DV_AL
U_TA364_GT11_LARM
U_FF415_GT46_L_AL
U_KB6_GT11_DV_AL
```

Comment: For help with your code: show your code (a [mcve] to be precise) and explain what about that code didn't work the way you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file contains only one *alarm* by line, you can use `Get-Content` to create a list of *alarms*:

```
$alarmList = Get-Content -Path .\data.txt
```

If your file contains *alarms* separated by a space (as in your example before edition) you may use the `Select-String` CmdLet to extract all alarms of your data file:

```
$alarmList = (Select-String -Path .\data.txt -Pattern '[^ ]+' -AllMatches).Matches.Value
```

The expression '[^ ]+' will capture strings of one or more characters without space.

Then, use `Group-Object` to count each occurence of alarm in the list:

```
$alarmList | Group-Object -NoElement
```

You'll obtain statistics like:

```
Count Name                                                                                                                                                                              
----- ----                                                                                                                                                                            
    1 D_TA204_GT1_DV_AL                                                                                                                                                               
    1 D_TA204_GT41_DV_AL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    4 U_TA364_GT11_LARM                                                                                                     
    2 U_FF415_GT46_L_AL
```

Finally, sending statistics in a CSV file:

```
(Select-String -Path '.\data.txt' -Pattern '[^ ]+' -AllMatches).Matches.Value |
Group-Object -NoElement |
ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation |
Out-File -FilePath '.\Statistics.csv'
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I need to read up on this command and powershell. What does '[^ ]+ mean? It seems to me that this script itself checks what unique values are in the file and counts them. Is this so?

Comment: Group-Object does the work, and as every line in data.txt is a key, Select-String with a RegEx that matches at least one non space character `[^ ]+` isn't neccessary at all.  `Get-Content .\data.txt |Group-Object -Noelement` is all you need.

Comment: Dan: I added some explanations. Don't forget to 'accept' the answer if it solution your problem. LotPings: the original sample (edited since) was separated by spaces. Thank-you for the '-NoElement' proposal !

Answer (score 1):

Although you did not show any own efforts, I decided to provide a tiny script:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Iterate over lines of `unik.txt`:
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ("unik.txt") do (
    rem // Count number of occurrences in `data.txt`:
    for /F %%J in ('^< "data.txt" find /C "%%I"') do (
        rem // Return TAB-separated item and count:
        echo/%%I    %%J
    )
)
```

Of course you can change the output order or format according to your needs.

Comment: Great. I had started using a three-row script and was able to output the number for a single one. Then Julien provided a fine powershell example covering it all. Will learn more about powershell it seems...

Answer (score 0):

A friend just showed me an alternative solution using AWK. I prefer powershell though. Thanks all.

```
awk "{s[$0]=s[$0] + 1}END{for (i in s) {print i, s[i]}}"  data.txt > t1
```