# Counting lines after grep finds a string

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I'd like to count the instances of 'text' after each 'header'. I'm using grep and awk but open to any tools. My file looks like this:

```
header1
text1
text2
text3
header2
text1
header3
header4
text1
text2
...
```

A great output would look like this

```
header1 3
header2 2
header3 0
header4 2
...
```

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781329/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-using-sed), but requires not counting the total occurrences and instead the occurrences between a certain string.

Comment: grep cannot do this, but awk is perfect. What have you tried? Please post some code.

Comment: Why `header2` is showing 2 when there is only `text1` below it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$  awk '{if (/header/) {h=$0; a[h]=0} if (/text/) {a[h]++}} END{for (i in a) {print i" "a[i]}}' file
header1 3
header2 1
header3 0
header4 2
```

- `{if (/header/) {h=$0; a[h]=0} if (/text/) {a[h]++}}` fills the array `a[]` with the number of matches of each "text" line after each "header" line.
- `END{for (i in a) {print i" "a[i]}}` prints the result after reading the file.

Comment: so what if the text contains `header`?

Comment: It is a possibility. Just updated taken it into consideration.

Comment: it's safe to assume those texts don't literally contain/start with `text`. I'm pretty sure that was just an example. check the other posted solution.

Comment: Check the question, please: `I'd like to count the instances of 'text' after each 'header'`.

Comment: Hmm.. let's see. @psny?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, the OP cannot get the notifications if he hasn't posted a comment in this answer. Why "Let's see?" it is clear on his question. My answer accomplishes it and I don't see any need to downvote.

Comment: I know he sees it. I was just indicating that at this point I'm waiting for him to resolve the dispute ;)

Comment: It works. Thanks! note: the text doesn't contain header (and it is well defined)

Answer (score 4):

This awk command does not store the entire file in memory:

```
awk '/^header/{if (head) print head,k;head=$1; k=0}!/^header/{k++}END{print head,k}' file
```

If you are only interested in counting the lines containing `text`, then change the script to this:

```
awk '/^header/{if (head) print head,k;head=$1; k=0}/text/{k++}END{print head,k}' file
```